# Entity Framework sending wrong date to update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working on an MVC 3 application in C# that is having trouble updating an entry in the table.

The update string that is being called from EF is sending in the date as such **(all other values in the where statement have been removed for clarity)**:

```
where [CreateDate] = '2012-09-24 19:12:08'
```

The actual database entry has the date and the sql data type is datetime2(7):

```
2012-09-24 19:12:08.6457698
```

When the code is executed the dates don't match and nothing is updated. I created my models using Reverse Engineering Code First from existing database. Here is my Model:

```
public class NPost
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int NPostID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title!")]
    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the body of the post!")]
    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one tag!")]
    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PublishDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Rating { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a topic!")]
    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string Topic { get; set; }

    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string TitleImage { get; set; }

    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string ListingImage { get; set; }

    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string BoxImage { get; set; }

    public virtual aspnet_Users aspnet_Users { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to do to get these dates to line up and work correctly?

Comment: Why on earth are you matching these values by timestamp? What if two rows get inserted during the same second?

Comment: The time stamp is not the Unique Identifier. I just removed all of the other where statements.

Comment: Where does the date come from that EF is using?

Comment: Then why does date need to be part of the where clause at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the cautions that others have expressed regarding what you're doing here.  However, we ought to have a direct answer to your question too!  I suspect that EF is treating your column as a SQL `datetime` value rather than the newer `datetime2` type.  So try the following.

You can use the [`[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) attribute on your property to indicate the exact database type to use, or the [`HasColumnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.hascolumntype%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method if you prefer fluent configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an exact match on dates seems error prone. Entity Framework should normally do the update based on the primary key, e.g. Where NPostId = 50.  Can you change the update in the controller to be based on ID?

```
var postById = context.Posts.Where(p => p.NPostId == id).First();
postById.Text = text;
...
context.Entry(postById).State = EntityState.Modified;
postById.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If someone picks the post from a list make sure that the ID is passed to the controller, that is the normal convention.  Then you can get the Post entity by ID and do the update based on that. Will update the post with an example.

Comment: Ended up being a unique identifier issue as the mapping done by code first created a key that used all the columns in the table. Fixing this solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the timestamp as a unique identifier, you have to guarantee that no two items can have the same time value.  If that's really what you want to do, set the precision of the CreateDate table column to datetime2(0) and set a unique key on the column.

HOWEVER...

To Aaron's point, using a timestamp as a unique identifier is probably not a good idea.  Use an autoincrementing field or `uniqueidentifier` (GUID-typed) field instead.